# How can ListView entries be transferred from Form2 to an identical ListView in Form1?

Tags: c#

Much has been written about it, but I have found nothing suitable for my problem. In a `ListView in Form2` data is inserted from textBoxes. The `Form2` is then closed via a `submit button`. This should transfer the entries to the identical `ListView` in`Form1`. This does work from textBox to textBox, but from ListView to ListView not. Is there a simple solution for this? Many Thanks.

Entries createt in `ListView1 form2`.

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;            

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("1");
        item.SubItems.Add(txtEntry_1.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(txtEntry_2.Text);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

In `form2` the following is written.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();            
        this.Close();
    }
```

And in `form1` then the following.

```
private void btnOpenForm2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Form2 frm1 = new Form2();
        frm1.ShowDialog();

        //listView to ListView does not work
        listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1] = frm1.listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1];

        //textBox to TextBox works
        txtTest1.Text = (Double.Parse(txtTest1.Text) + Double.Parse(frm1.txtTest2.Text)).ToString("0.00");              
    }
```

Update: A simple solution. `Form2`

```
private void btnInsert_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                
            Form2 frm1 = new Form2();
            frm1.ShowDialog();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in frm1.listView1.Items)
            {
                this.listView1.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
            }
    }
```

and  `Form1`

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();            
        this.Close();           
    }
```

Comment: Define 'transfer'. Do you want a copy or do you want to move the Items? Also: _Doesn't work_ is not  a helpful problem description!

Comment: `@TaW` thanks for the answer, both are possible. The entries in `Form2 listView1` can also be deleted afterwards.

Comment: cant you just make form 2 with a parameter that accepts the reference of form1's listview? This would then technically just be the same listview in either form.

Comment: To Move: create a reference `lvi` to the item, then remove from lv1 and add to lv2. To copy : make a clone and add it `listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)lvi.Clone())` - Copying single subitems needs to first create them and possibly empty ones before..

Comment: `@Morten Bork` this is a good idea, maybe you have a small example for that?

Comment: `@TaW` thx, I will try that.

Comment: Do not clone.  It will give you issues.  Use an instance of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: `@jdweng` thank you, will check this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. the simplest solution looks like this. See in the Update.